# wait forkjoin to render html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, fork-join

I have a `forkjoin` with 2 calls. In the `html`, I need to wait until the response of the `forkjoin` arrived. Is there any way to do it with the `async` pipe? I read in another post that `async` is only for `observables` and `promises`. I tried to do it with `*ngIf`, but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance

> TS

```
var1: string;
var2: string;

 forkJoin(
   this.call1(),
   this.call2()
 ).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
   this.var1 = res1;
   this.var2 = res2;
   }, err => console.log(err));
```

> HTML

```
<div class="col">
   <label class="labelEsp">Var 1:</label>
   <span class="spanEsp uppercase" >{{ var1 }}</span>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <label class="labelEsp"> Var 2:</label>
    <span class="spanEsp" >{{ var2 }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you put on your `*ngIf` initially

Comment: Initially I put ```*ngIf="var1 | async; else loading"``` and the template ```<ng-template #loading>Loading Data...</ng-template> ```, but It always show Loading Data

Comment: If you are already returning the observable, there  is not need for the `async` pipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep using the subscription in `typescript` and hide and show the HTML in view using a flag.

Something like this will do:

```
dataReady = false;
forkJoin(
   this.call1(),
   this.call2()
 ).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
   this.var1 = res1;
   this.var2 = res2;
   },
 (err) => console.log(err),
 () => {
    this.dataReady = true
    // complete block
  }
);

<ng-container *ngIf="dataReady else loading">
  <div class="col">
    <label class="labelEsp">Var 1:</label>
    <span class="spanEsp uppercase" >{{ var1 }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <label class="labelEsp"> Var 2:</label>
      <span class="spanEsp" >{{ var2] }}</span>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  loading...
</ng-template>
```

If you want to do it using an `async` pipe itself, then you can have something like:

```
data = forkJoin(
   this.call1(),
   this.call2()
 )


<ng-container *ngIf="data | async as resolvedData else loading">
  <div class="col">
    <label class="labelEsp">Var 1:</label>
    <span class="spanEsp uppercase" >{{ resolvedData[0] }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <label class="labelEsp"> Var 2:</label>
      <span class="spanEsp" >{{ resolvedData[1] }}</span>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  loading...
</ng-template>
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwpwya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It works fine ! Finally I sed the async method .Thank you!